# Mongodb PojoCodec Found property not present in the ClassModel: id

Tags: mongodb, serialization, pojo, codec, bson

Be me, perform aggregate query on MongoDb:

```
db.Rubrica.aggregate([
{$match: {"fiscalCode": "asfjhsdfhgsdfugsdf"}},
{$project: {
    "_id":0,
    "contactsHeaders":"$contacts.header",
}}
]);
```

Get the result:

```
{
    "contactsHeaders" : [
        {
            "id" : "7b47c1637cde49d182b96bcc33d21d0d",
            "alias" : "VOL LISTA",
            "type" : "L"
        },
        {
            "id" : "ab31c06ecce244bea4ab5b45b89f4fdc",
            "alias" : "VOL FEDRO",
            "type" : "S"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now in Java i try to deserialize the Document in:

```
public class ListOfHeadersWrapper implements Serializable  {
     List<Header> contactsHeaders;
....
....

public class Header implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String alias;
    private TypeEnum type;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
....
....
```

What I get is:

```
{
    "contacts": [
    {
      "id": null,
      "alias": "VOL LISTA",
      "type": "L"
    },
    {
      "id": null,
      "alias": "VOL FEDRO",
      "type": "S"
    }
  ]
}
```

**id** is always **null**. Logs says *Found property not present in the ClassModel: id*.

If I deserialize the thing manually with Jackson:

`(new ObjectMapper()).readValue(res.toJson(), ListOfHeadersWrapper.class).toString()`

I get the correct result:

```
ListOfHeadersWrapper{contactsHeaders=[Header{id='7b47c1637cde49d182b96bcc33d21d0d', alias='VOL
```

WHY????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **@BsonProperty("id")** does the trick:

```
public class Header implements Serializable {
    @BsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    ...
    ...
```

This I think only happens for CosmosDb when used with MongoApi.